# Does an online business selling across the USA would need to file for foreign qualification in each state?

Tags: united-states, fees, limited-liability-company

I have been looking at the rules for an all online transactional company. If I make sales in all US states, do I need to file for foreign qualification if I have a Nevada LLC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to file foreign qualification in any State you have physical presence in (warehouses, offices, etc). Including the State from which you personally operate (if it is not Nevada). You don't need to register in States to which you ship products.

Comment: Much appreciated!